# R package tidyverse in MX Linux 19.4

Tags: r, linux, tidyverse

I am using MX Linux 19.4 and have installed R 3.6.1 with RStudio 2021.09.0.

I would like to use the tidyverse 1.3.1 package on this system.  I ran `install.packages("tidyverse")` and that completed without errors.  Then I tried to run the command: `library(tidyverse)` to be able to use the package in RStudio.  I got the following messages which I don't understand:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to create bus connection: Host is down
```

What do these messages mean?  The RStudio console then goes on to indicate that various tidyverse packages such as ggplot2 have been attached.  After that there are warnings indicating that:

```
1: In system("timedatectl", intern = TRUE) :
  running command 'timedatectl' had status 1
2: In readLines("/etc/timezone") :
  incomplete final line found on '/etc/timezone'
```

How can I determine if the tidyverse has been installed correctly?  Thank you.